# Difficulty dealing with encoding in SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I'm trying to get information from a SQLite file, and I when I run a query, the information is returned with ASCII encoding. I'm using the code below to put the returned information into a string.

```
[NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

When I try to use UTF8 encoding to put the returned information into a string, it doesn't work. The code below is used in the app currently on the store.

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
```

The string is null. How can I convert the SQLite file so that it is encoded with UTF8? The current version of the app on the store uses the latter code above, so I need to figure out how to convert the file, instead of changing the code in the app.

Comment: I think you'll get more hits if you changed the title to something like " Change SQLite encoding? " "SQLite encoding problems" or maybe "Difficulty dealing with encoding in SQLite" Hope it works out!

Comment: What encoding was used to create the data in the sqlite database? If it was written using ASCII encoding then what you are doing is correct.

Comment: @rmaddy The current app on the App Store attempts to read the database using UTF8 encoding. Do you know how to convert the database so it works with UTF8?

Comment: @rmaddy See my edit. The following doesn't work: `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];` That returns a null string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `const void *sqlite3_column_text16(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);` with [stringWithCharacters:length:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithCharacters:length:) (UTF16)

```
const unichar *text = sqlite3_column_text16(_sqlite_stmt, columnIndex);
if (text) {
   NSUInteger length = sqlite3_column_bytes16(_sqlite_stmt, columnIndex)/sizeof(unichar);
   article = [NSString stringWithCharacters:text length:length];
}
```

Comment: The version of the app on the App Store attempts to read the database file with UTF8 encoding, so I need to figure out how to convert the database file so that it works with UTF8. Do you know how?

Comment: See my edit. The following doesn't work: `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];` This returns a null string.

Comment: @JackHumphries per http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html "[if t]he initial content is UTF-8 text and sqlite3_column_bytes16() or sqlite3_column_text16() is called [then t]he content must be converted to UTF-16." — `sqlite3_column_text16` doesn't imply anything about storage. Though the same is true of `sqlite3_column_text` so it's peculiar that what you're already doing isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
char *title = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:title];
```

Working fine for me !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know how I can change the database file, as the app is already on the App Store. I can't change the code without releasing an update.